# Logic App Designer is not displaying the Logic App Flow

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic App which was normally running and is still getting triggered if I call it through Postman. Last days I can not see the flow in designer (when I click edit), or see the Flow in runs History. Please advice.

I tried even to  go to "Logic App Code View" to get the **json** code and tried to re-import it hoping it will display the logic app flow, but even the json code is not displayed (stucks on loading / displaying 3 dots)

Comment: I’d raise that one with Microsoft.

Comment: @andreas charidemou once try clearing your browser cache and cookies,  try using a different browser to access the Azure portal and You can try logging out of your account and logging back . Any one of these may help

Comment: Thanks @vijaya ! I cleared cookies and cached and browsed using Inprivate Window. This worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Last days I can not see the flow in designer (when I click edit), or see the Flow in runs History....
```

- As I mentioned in comments **clearing your browser cache and cookies** is one way to resolve your problem.
- To view your lost workflow, you can **access the Azure portal using a different browser/Inprivate Window**.
- Also, you can try **logging out of your account and logging back again** also sometimes helpful in this logic App workflow not displaying in designer view.
- As you mentioned tried in designer flow and also tried code view. Apart from these in **Versions** also  we can check the flow of logic App workflows earlier created.
- Created logic App>>Development Tools>>Versions. As shown in below images in versions we can select our previously crated and modified workflows.
  [image]
- After selecting the version, we can choose our workflow in either designer view or code view as shown in below image.
  [image]